# How can get the current virtual path without file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Request.Path will get the current Path name with file name such as:

```
C:/......./Personal/Items.aspx
```

How can I get the only Path name such as:

```
C:/......./Personal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GetParent()` method on [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx).

```
DirectoryInfo parent = Directory.GetParent(requestPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to get the directory part of a path.

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Personal\Items.aspx");
// path is @"C:\Personal"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the **virtual** path:

```
 Page.TemplateSourceDirectory
```

See the below answers for the **physical** path.

Answer (score 0):

you can get Directory Path from System.IO.FileInfo

```
var fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
var result = fInfo.DirectoryName;
```